# AS3: Loading different, externa text values on MouseOver

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm stuck with this thing for a while now. I'm working on a map that displays popup with dynamically loaded text when you hover over specific objects (mc's). mc_box is my popup clip with text fields (aTxt, bTxt) and 1, 2 are objects I'm hovering over. This is part of the code I'm using, I figured I have to get the target name and data loaded from the text file, but I'm really not sure how can I go from here:

```
mc_box.visible=false;

var targetName:String;
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, getName);
function getName(e:MouseEvent):void {
    targetName = e.target.name;
}

var lv:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
lv.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
lv.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    txtData = e.target.data
}
lv.load(new URLRequest("text.txt"));

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseover, true);
function mouseover(e:MouseEvent) {
    mc_box.visible=true;
    mc_box.x=mouseX+5;
    mc_box.y=mouseY+5;
    mc_box.startDrag();
}

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseout, true);
function mouseout(e:MouseEvent) {
    mc_box.visible=false;
}
```

The text file looks like this:

```
&a_1=some text 1
&b_1=some text 2

&a_2=some other text 1
&b_2=some other text 2
```

And my question is how the hell can I get it to display text fields according to the object name I mouseOver on? I've been trying to do something like this:

```
mc_box.aTxt.text=e.target.data.('a_'+targetName);
mc_box.bTxt.text=e.target.data.('b_'+targetName);
```

but obviously it won't work. Please help...

Comment: Why would you load the text dynamically from a file while having the objects at fixed positions? Why not simply have the text in the code?

Comment: True, I wanted the code to be simple and short, but I'll guess I'll do that.

Comment: In your example it would be mc_box.bTxt.text=e.target.data['b_'+targetName]; But why don't you load the text on startup instead of loading it on rollover, store it in some kind of object or dictionary and then just look up values on rollover ? XML would be also a good way to store your texts. You could also embed your XML or text file into the application so you would not even need to load it but just parse it on startup and then lookup values. This way you would still have all texts in a separate file and not spread all over your code

Comment: Thank you! I do have another problem now, my mouseover function returns undefined values with no properties. How do I use it now?

Comment: Can you update your code in the question to reflect the changes you've made that are leading to this new problem? Or else post a new question